# sql server 2008 security

Tags: sql-server

1-when adding new user to database there is schemas owned by this user whet exactly does it do and if you add permission to it you cant remove it later and is it connected to default schema

2- please explain  take ownership permission

thank you

Answer (score 1):

1) Beginning in SQL Server 2005, each object belongs to a database schema. A database schema is a distinct namespace that is separate from a database user. You can think of a schema as a container of objects. Schemas can be created and altered in a database, and users can be granted access to a schema. A schema can be owned by any user, and schema ownership is transferable.

To resolve the names of securables that are not fully qualified (**[DatabaseServer].[DatabaseName].[DatabaseSchema].[DatabaseObject]**), SQL Server 2000 used name resolution to check the schema owned by the calling database user and the schema owned by dbo. In SQL Server 2005, each user can be assigned a default schema.

2) See [Permissions Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191291.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There is a concise explanation of schmas in SQL server here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx

"The behavior of schemas changed in SQL Server 2005. Schemas are no longer equivalent to database users; each schema is now a distinct namespace that exists independently of the database user who created it. In other words, a schema is simply a container of objects. A schema can be owned by any user, and its ownership is transferable."

That should clear most things up for you